# Encode number in frontend (for Game) to keep it secret

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to encode a number so, that in frontend (with javascript) i could know it and calculate with it without hackers to find this number out?

I am doing a browser game which uses server-side logic and client-side logic.

For example:
Enemy health is 100. This could be encoded inside backend(server).
Turret damage per second = 1. Backend knows it, frontend knows it.
I want to calculate how long left until it is 0 (until enemy died by turret).
But i want that hackers would not find out that enemy has 100 health by looking on my source code and rescripting it.
I can not set something like: will_die_at = after 10 minutes. Because players would find out that this Enemy has low health by knowing exact death time. Enemy health can vary from 10 to 100k. And for strategy purpose this should be not known.
I believe any decoding functions on frontend which would parse this number can also be found out by hackers and they can get this number anyways :)

And the other problem is that i can not ask server every minute or Enemy has already died. Because there are hundreds of enemies on field. My server will be totally overloaded. This should be done only in frontend :)

This is a server-based browser HTML5 MMO. I believe some people will try hard to break my code and find out these numbers and make useful scripts/helpers/paches to sell for other players. This will lead to unfair PvP.

---

So far i have two options:
1. Just show players the exact health number of Enemy.
2. Backend knows exact death time of this Enemy. For example Date.now() is 14:00:00, and death time - today 15:12:37. Frontend doesnt know that. But i can't ask server every 1-5-10 seconds - is it? is it? So my server gives to frontend one number: 14:02:37. And the frontend requests the server only every 10 minutes after this given time - is it? And the server responses totally 6 times - as "no", this Enemy is not death yet, but you don't know how long you will repeat this question until it is died. And the 7th time it responses - "yes, it died just before a second", because server knows it has died. So, this will give some spam to server, but not too high and probably it can handle that spam when it is so rare. And hackers cant find out health of the Enemy.

Comment: `And the other problem is that i can not ask server every minute or Enemy has already died. Because there are hundreds of enemies on field. My server will be totally overloaded. This should be done only in frontend.` This is an incorrect thought. This should all be calculated server side and only rendering should be done client side. The server needs to be the master state and the clients need to respect any data in provides.

Comment: Yes i understand this. But it will overload my server. I was looking for an option, of this is even possible. But so far it seems that it is not possible and what i can - just show this health on frontend and players will know exact time when this enemy dies. Less strategy in my game, but technically i have no other options :)

Comment: As far as strategy design you could try asking in the [game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange to see if they have any ideas on how you could build some strategy around it.

Comment: I was considering this. But this is more technical question than design. Because my project is already too complex to explain my current design :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the browser is entirely under the user's control, this is not possible. You can obfuscate your code and values, but not encrypt them so that nobody else could decrypt them. Because if you encrypt it un-decryptably, your program would not be able to decrypt it either.

Server interaction is necessary because you need a "protected area" to hide your secrets.

Comment: Yea, the same i trough :D I trough maybe there is already invented something for this purpose :D

Comment: Why not use the server?

Comment: Because i cant spam my server asking every second/minute or this enemy is died. There are hundreds of enemies on field. There are 2-5 visible such fields. There are 10k fields on one server

Comment: I could probably somehow clever use cron jobs for all enemies and with sockets push notifications like every 10 seconds if it died.. I dont care how much it is complicated, but that sounds same - too overloaded. My current option is to give up and just show the health without hiding it. Then i can easily calculate everything. But players can be not very happy. I dont know other option for now :)

Comment: What you should do is run the same logic client side and server side, that way there isn't much noticeable lag on the client. Then frequently, how frequent depends on game design and hardware capabilities, send the updated game state from the server to clients. It isn't uncommon for fast paced games to be sending update packets many times a second.

Comment: This is a long-paced game. Like travian, but with big map made of tiles. And on these tiles are many chess-figures. Every chess figure has an army inside of it. So i wanna hide how many armies are inside this chess figure. Players can also build turrets which shoot enemies in real-time (looks like, but its precalculated in server).  Turrets do damage depending on total health of all units in this army. So i think maybe i show total health, but i dont show which units, how much strength they have and other stats, just total health.. For now..

Comment: I found possible solution - posted it on edit of my post.